# Getting Defects via 2.0 API

Tags: rally

Having problems pulling the defects out of a story on the kanban board.  One of the features we have on our custom board is to list out the defects tied to the story, inside the card.

I had this working in 2.0p2, but while porting my code over to 2.0rc1, I cant seem to get back the defect array.

I used to call this:

```
var defectArray = this.card.getRecord().get("Defects");
```

Then iterate through them in typical for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < defectArray.length; i++) {
  var defect = defectArray[i];
  ...
}
```

The older API used to return an object array on the .get("Defects), and now it doesn't.

I am sure I am missing something, any help would be great !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default 2.0rc1 uses the new WSAPI v2.0.  For performance reasons it is no longer possible to do this in 2.x versions of WSAPI.  Now each object collection has its own unique ref uri.
This means these collections can now be separately queried, paged, sorted and filtered.

Fetching Defects on a story will now return an object containing the count and the uri from which to retrieve the collection data.
The ref uri is generally of the format /type/oid/collection (e.g. /hierarchicalrequirement/12345/defects).

All records now have a [getCollection](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.domain.WsapiModel-method-getCollection) method for retrieving child collection data.
This method will return an instance of [Rally.data.CollectionStore](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.CollectionStore) for working with the child collection.

The following example shows how retrieve associated defect information for a story in SDK 2.0rc1/WSAPI 2.x:

```
var defectInfo = story.get('Defects');
var defectCount = defectInfo.Count;

story.getCollection('Defects').load({
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'State'],
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        Ext.Array.each(records, function(defect) {
            //each record is an instance of the defect model
            console.log(defect.get('FormattedID') + ' - ' +
                defect.get('Name') + ': ' + defect.get('State'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this does work, however, I was hoping for a more sequential answer, this gets me out of sync, while writing my custom info out to the card.  I will have to revamp some code to allow for the callback to work on this one.  Marked as correct, since this is how you have to get defects now.

Comment: Yes, we are still learning our way around this API as well.  The GA version of the SDK should have support for promises so you will be able to write a lot of async code like this in a more synchronous style.  Also, here is a recently published guide on WSAPI 2.x collections: http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/guide/collections_in_v2

Comment: Kyle, this is super-helpful. Question when I try to pull the Artifacts collection from a Changeset using: `record.getCollection('Artifacts').load(....` where the record came back as a query on Changesets. I'm getting back a `Uncaught Invalid model type specified: Artifact`. Is it possible to pull back a generic Artifacts collection like this?

Comment: We ran into this recently as well.  I'm pretty sure this is a defect.  I'll file it.

Answer (score 1):

You may get back the defects like this:

```
var defects = story.getCollection('Defects');
```

Here is a full code that uses 2.0rc1 and accesses the defects collection on user stories. In the code I build a grid, but the part of accessing the collection will hopefully help.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'UserStory',
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','Defects'],
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
    });
},

_createGrid: function(stories) {
     this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: stories,
            pageSize: 100
        }),

        columnCfgs: [
            {
               text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID'
            },
            {
                text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Defect Count', dataIndex: 'DefectCount'
            },
            {
                text: 'Defects', dataIndex: 'Defects', flex: 1, emptyCellText: 'zero',
                renderer: function(value) {
                    if (value) {
                        return value.join(',');
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

    });
},
_onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
            var stories = [];
            var pendingDefects = data.length;

            Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                        var s  = {
                            FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: story.get('Name'),
                            DefectCount: story.get('Defects').Count,
                            Defects: []
                        };

                        var defects = story.getCollection('Defects');
                        defects.load({
                            fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                            callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                Ext.Array.each(records, function(defect){
                                    s.Defects.push(defect.get('FormattedID'));    
                                }, this);

                                --pendingDefects;
                                if (pendingDefects === 0) {
                                    this._createGrid(stories);
                                }
                            },
                            scope: this
                        });
                        stories.push(s);
            }, this);
}
```

});